# How can I resize UIviewController's view?

Tags: ios4

I have a customView on main window, so I want my Viewcontroller's view to resize so that it doesn't overlaps with the custom view on main window.

I tried setting frame property of my VC's view in the viewDidLoad method but it automatically resizes to full window height.

```
self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 200);
```

But when my view is loaded/appears it resizes it to full window height (that is 480px).

Am I trying to do something which is not possible?

Comment: If you need only (0,0, 320, 200) frame size, then you can add subView with this frame size.

Comment: consider adding a new UIView with 320x200 instead of resizing current view.

Comment: @Sisu & Shivan.. Yes I can do it by adding a subview of required size, but I need to do it in not just one, but many view controllers. so I was wondering if I can do it by resizing the frame size rather than adding a subview to each VC.
btw is it possible to resize the VC's view.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 200.0)];
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];  //optional For You
[window addSubview:loadingView];
```

Try this, I Hope you will get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

try `myViewController.view addSubview:self.window` after setting the frame property.

And try to make the `mainwindow` programmatically to have more control over it.

hope it helps..